# NMAKE - Call Command Multiple Times

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have an assembler that will not take multiple input files. It takes one .s files and produces a corresponding .o file.

```
EXECUTABLE_NAME = test.exe

SRC_FILES= \
  file1.s \
  file2.s

$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) : $(SRC_FILES)
  myasm -o file1.o $(SRC_FILES)
  mylink -o $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) -s file1.o
```

How would I modify my makefile to run asm as follows:

```
  myasm -o file1.o file1.s
  myasm -o file2.o file2.s
  mylink -o $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) -s file1.o file2.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a rule that tells nmake how to build your .o from your .s.  The syntax is a little gnarly, but something like this:

```
EXECUTABLE_NAME = test.exe

SRC_FILES= \
  file1.s \
  file2.s

OBJ_FILES = \
  .\file1.o \
  .\file2.o

.SUFFIXES : .s

SRC_DIR = .
OBJ_DIR = .

{$(SRC_DIR)}.s{$(OBJ_DIR)}.o:
  myasm -o $@ $<

$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) : $(OBJ_FILES)
  mylink -o $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) -s $(OBJ_FILES)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps - I will give that a try when I get home and hopefully accept your answer. Gnarly indeed - makefiles have always been a bit fiddly for me. Usually get one and just add to it over time.